# 'Wide character in subroutine entry" - UTF-8 encoded cyrillic words as sequence of bytes

Tags: perl, unicode, utf-8, md5, cyrillic

I am working on an Android word game with a large dictionary -

[image: app screenshot]

The words (over 700 000) are kept as separate lines in a text file (and then put in an SQLite database).

To protect my dictionary, I'd like to encode all words which are longer than 3 chars with md5. (I don't obfuscate short words and words with rare Russian letters `ъ` and `э`, because I'd like to list them in my app).

So here is my script which I try to run with **perl v5.18.2** on Mac Yosemite:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use utf8;
use Digest::MD5 qw(md5_hex);

binmode(STDIN, ":utf8");
#binmode(STDOUT, ":raw");
binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");

while(<>) {
        chomp;
        next if length($_) < 2; # ignore 1 letter junk
        next if /жы/;           # impossible combination in Russian
        next if /шы/;           # impossible combination in Russian

        s/ё/е/g;
    
        if (length($_) <= 3 || /ъ/ || /э/) { # do not obfuscate short words
                print "$_\n";                # and words with rare letters
                next;
        }

        print md5_hex($_) . "\n";            # this line crashes
}
```

As you can see, I have to use cyrillic letters in the source code of my Perl script - that is why I've put `use utf8;` on its top.

However my real problem is that `length($_)` reports too high values (probably reporting number of bytes instead of number of characters).

So I have tried adding:

```
binmode(STDOUT, ":raw");
```

or:

```
binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");
```

But the script then dies with **Wide character in subroutine entry** at the line with `print md5_hex($_)`.

Please help me to fix my script.

I run it as:

```
perl ./generate-md5.pl < words.txt > encoded.txt
```

and here is example **words.txt** data for your convenience:

```
а
аб
абв
абвг
абвгд
съемка
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`md5_hex` expects a string of bytes for input, but you're passing a decoded string (a string of Unicode Code Points). Explicitly encode the string.

```
use strict;
use utf8;
use Digest::MD5;
use Encode;
# ....
# $_ is assumed to be utf8 encoded without check
print Digest::MD5::md5_hex(Encode::encode_utf8($_)),"\n";
# Conversion only when required:
print Digest::MD5::md5_hex(utf8::is_utf8($_) ? Encode::encode_utf8($_) : $_),"\n";
```

Comment: Thanks `md5_hex()` was indeed causing the crash. I overlooked that part in [perldoc Digest::MD5](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Digest-MD5/MD5.pm)

Comment: Perfect! I had similar problem with base64 convert of Cyrillic (and other) letters, other than Latin. I have just added it and it works like a charm! Thank you and @AlexanderFarber!

Answer (score 5):

> my real problem is that length($_) reports too high values

Yes, you are reading from the `ARGV` file handle and haven't set its encoding to UTF-8

You can use the `open` pragma to fix this. Instead of all your `binmode` statements, use

```
use open qw/ :std :encoding(utf8) /;
```

which will change the default open mode for all filehandles, including the standard ones, to `:encoding(utf8)`

Answer (score 1):

if u use Mojolicious then replace to_json to encode_json will solve the problem.

From the documentation of JSON module, to_json keyword:
If you want to write a modern perl code which communicates to outer world, you should use encode_json (supposed that JSON data are encoded in UTF-8).
and I can't foresee a non UTF-8 world out there.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using perl version 5.0 and above then this can be resolved by changing to_json to encode_json